# Not able to view Firebase Database from console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing data to Firebase DB through java code,but I am not able to view the database from *Firebase console*.
I have set database permissions to public but can not see any data.

I am referring [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170499/Firebase-Realtime-Database-By-Example-with-Android?fid=1917789&df=90&mpp=25&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed) tutorial

And here is my code to write the data into database:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.child("users").child("id").setValue(userDetails.getUserId());
```

Please tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my mistake! `userDetails.getuserId` is null; and one can not create child with null value.(duh)